# How to retrieve multiple XML siblings - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I have searched thoroughly and not found any examples or guidance on how I can query and retrieve the values of multiple XML siblings.

There are plenty of examples on how to retrieve a single sibling value.

For example given the following XML fragment:

```
<StoreSurvey>
  <AnnualSales>800000</AnnualSales>
  <AnnualRevenue>80000</AnnualRevenue>
  <BankName>United Security</BankName>
  <BusinessType>BM</BusinessType>
  <YearOpened>1996</YearOpened>
  <Specialty>Mountain</Specialty>
  <SquareFeet>21000</SquareFeet>
  <Brands>2</Brands>
  <Internet>ISDN</Internet>
  <NumberEmployees>13</NumberEmployees>
  <Products Type="Bikes">
    <Product>Mountain</Product>
    <Product>Road</Product>
    <Product>Racing</Product>
  </Products>
  <Products Type="Clothes">
    <Product>Jerseys</Product>
    <Product>Jackets</Product>
    <Product>Shorts</Product>
  </Products>
</StoreSurvey>
```

If I want to retrieve the value of `<AnnualSales>`, I can execute the following statement in query analyzer:

```
SELECT Survey_untyped.query('/StoreSurvey/AnnualSales') 
FROM Stores;
```

The result set will properly display

```
<AnnualSales>800000</AnnualSales>
```

However, what if I want to retrieve both `<AnnualSales>` AND `<AnnualRevenue>`? How would I do that?

The query should provide a result set looking like:

```
<AnnualSales>800000</AnnualSales>
<AnnualRevenue>80000</AnnualRevenue>
```

Or what if I want three of the sibling values “BankName” in addition to those values? Result set would look like this:

```
  <AnnualSales>800000</AnnualSales>
  <AnnualRevenue>80000</AnnualRevenue>
  <BankName>United Security</BankName>
```

Does anyone know the answer to that?

Answer (score 2):

This XPath, which uses the [**`self::` axis**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes),

```
/StoreSurvey/*[self::AnnualSales or self::AnnualRevenue or self::BankName]
```

will select

```
<AnnualSales>800000</AnnualSales>
<AnnualRevenue>80000</AnnualRevenue>
<BankName>United Security</BankName>
```

from your XML, as requested.

Comment: Thank you, I have not seen any references that use that use that syntax "self" etc.  Could you please post a link to that?  (I have been looking at standard x-query examples, etc.)

Comment: actually, now that i look I see "self" in there, but it was described as selecting "the current node"  Never saw any examples like your's but thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time. Thanks again.

Comment: @SharmaVenkati: Answer updated with self:: axis link per your request.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.